# Artifactory - User Management menus hang after upgrade

Tags: artifactory

We have an Artifactory Pro (7.17.11) container running in production behind an Apache reverse proxy. Apache is using Kerberos authtype. On a test machine we've set up the same configuration but running an Artifactory Pro (7.63.14) container. Authentication still works as before in automatically logging users in using their Kerberos principal (e.g., "joe" from ""joe@BUNKO.COM"). Anytime a menu under "User Management" is accessed however, the page switches to the login page briefly and then ends up on an "Authenticating" screen forever. (https://artifactory2.bunko.com/ui/login/sso/http)

I've tried setting up a basic Apache configuration based on the documentation for HTTP SSO security but it behaves the same way.

Apache artifactory.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    
    ServerName artifactory2.bunko.com
    
    LogLevel Debug
    <LocationMatch "/*" >
        SSLRequireSSL
        AuthType Kerberos
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
        KrbServiceName HTTP/artifactory1.bunko.com@BUNKO.COM
        KrbAuthRealms BUNKO.COM
        Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/krb5.keytab
        KrbLocalUserMapping on
        KrbVerifyKDC on
        KrbServiceName HTTP
        require user joe
        
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
        
    </LocationMatch>
    
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} (.*)
    RewriteRule (.*) - [E=my_server_port:%1]
    
    #Note: In the following, the REQUEST_SCHEME header is supported only by Apache versions 2.4 and    above:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} (.*)
    RewriteRule (.*) - [E=my_scheme:%1]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
    RewriteRule (.*) - [E=my_custom_host:%1]
    
    RewriteRule ^/$  /artifactory/webapp/ [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/artifactory(/)?$  /artifactory/webapp/ [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/artifactory/webapp$  /artifactory/webapp/ [R,L]
    
    RequestHeader set Host %{my_custom_host}e
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port %{my_server_port}e
    
    #Note: In the following, {my_scheme} requires a module that is supported only by Apache version 2.4 and above:
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto %{my_scheme}e
    RequestHeader set X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url %{my_scheme}e://artifactory2.bunko.com/artifactory
    
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    ProxyPass "/artifactory/" http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=2400
    ProxyPassReverse "/artifactory/" http://localhost:8081/artifactory/
    
    ## SSL directives
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile      "/etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard.bunko.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard.bunko.com.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/root_bundle.crt"
    SSLProxyEngine On
    
</VirtualHost>
```